# Why can I import a module from a path I removed?

Tags: python, pytest, python-module

### tl;dr

I create a dummy module module in `/tmp`, `insert` its path do `sys.path`, import the dummy module, `del` it when it's not needed anymore, remove it `sys.path` and I am still able to import it. Why?

### Full question

Consider this pytest fixture code and its comments:

```
def test_function(temp_dir):
    with open(os.path.join(temp_dir, 'dum.py'), 'w') as f:
        f.write("""
class A:
    \"\"\"
    test docstring
    \"\"\"
    test: int
    test_2: str = "asdf"

class B(A):
    pass
        """)
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(1, temp_dir)
    assert temp_dir in sys.path  # assertion passes
    # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
    import dum  # import successful

    yield dum

    # teardown executed after each usage of the fixture
    del dum  # deletion successful
    sys.path.remove(temp_dir)  # removing from path successful
    assert temp_dir not in sys.path  # assertion passes
    with pytest.raises(ModuleNotFoundError):  # fails - importing dum is successful
        import dum
```

Why? How do I actually remove it? It happens even when I force sys.path to be empty by executing `sys.path = []`. There is no `dum.py` anywhere in the project directory. Am I missing something? Is Python caching the imported modules even after their deletion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you import a module once, the next time you want to import it, Python first checks the collection of already imported modules, and uses the module that was already loaded. Therefore, the second time you import a module, `sys.path` is not even consulted.

This is essential, if you think of it: suppose you are directly importing some modules, and each of them uses, some other modules, and so on. If a module had to be retrieved from disk and parsed, every time an `import` statement was encountered, you would be spending and awful lot of time just waiting for modules to load.

It is also worth noting that the second time a module A imports a module B, nothing really happens. There are ways to explicitly reload an already-loaded module, but usually, you do not want to do that (web servers with live update are a notable exception).

Comment: How can I access this collection?

Comment: `sys.modules` is (I think) what you want.

Comment: Neat! Thanks, `sys.modules` was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Great and detailed information was provided by [Amitai Irron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4022580/amitai-irron) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62217061/5743194), so go there to understand *why*. To answer the question of *how to actually remove it* (and not be able to import it again), you need to execute not only all the deletions for the original question but also:

```py
del sys.modules['dum']
```

This removes the module from `sys.modules` which is keeping all the cached modules. Thanks to [0x5453](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3282436/0x5453) for pointing me to `sys.modules`.